# How do I get the expansion of $(x^2+2)^{−1}$ to the $x^3$ term

Tags: binomial-theorem

How do I get the expansion of $(x^2+2)^{−1}$ to the $x^3$ term

I don't really know how I have to use the formula here.
In wich form do I have to put $(x^2+2)^{−1}$?

Do i need to factorise it ?

Comment: @Integrator: He's probably asking similar questions because he doesn't have much of a handle on this and that answer in the similar post might be a tad bit out of his comprehension.

Comment: @Nick, if the answer is outside one's comprehension, one should add comments to the answers and ask for clarification, not repost.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: I agree with you entirely. But I'd like to make to make two things very clear, you can't close this question because it's not *exactly* the same as the other and second, most importantly, **this user has yet to make any comments**. I'm thinking he/she doesn't how.

Comment: @Nick, I agree. My main point was to instruct user164612 to use comments. I think it is reasonable to close very similar questions as duplicates unless the OP states why the similar question does not help here (including the possibility that they don't understand the answers or cannot generalize them). There rarely are verbatim duplicates. (I haven't voted to close this one.)

Comment: @user164612, can you explain why you want to ask this question in addition to the earlier one? They are very similar. You can ask for clarification to the answers by making comments.

Answer (score 5):

**Outline:** Note that 
$$(x^2+2)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$ Then use the expansion $\frac{1}{1-t}=1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots$, valid for $|t|\lt 1$, with $t=-\frac{x^2}{2}$.